# What happens after you reach the Salesforce daily Email limit?

Tags: email, salesforce

In Salesforce you can set up various workflow processes or build API apps that send email. For most standard Salesforce orgs, there is a limit of 1000 emails per day. (e.g. see [here](http://community.salesforce.com/t5/General-Development/questions-about-daily-email-limit/m-p/73236))

I can't find any info on what happens after you reach the limit.

e.g. what sort of errors occur, and are administrators automatically notified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll throw an exception (I can't remember the exact message). I've gotten these from time to time and I *think* they can't be caught. A quick way to check would be create an anonymous block with an isFuture method that sends 10 emails inside of a loop. Call this isFuture method inside of another loop (also 10x) and you'll send 100 emails without hitting governor limits.

Of course you'll have to run your code 11x to get the email exception. This is a pretty shite way to do it, but it's better than clicking a button 1000x.